# fatal error: libs\Message.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, header-files, atmelstudio

I am trying to compile an Arduino project using Atmel Studio. When I put my header files in the same directory as the project file, and try to include them, it works fine.

```
#include "Message.h"
```

edit: including the absolute path also works.

```
#include "C:\...\libs\Message.h"
```

but this is not a good practice and I want to include my files in a relative manner in the 'libs' folder. but moving the same file in that folder and addressing it brings up the "no such file or directory" error.

```
#include "libs\Message.h"
```

or

```
#include "libs/Message.h"
```

further explanations:
IDE is running on windows.
I am sure this is not a misspell, because even the IDE comes up with the same suggestion.
I tried running IDE as Admin, so that permissions somehow don't interfere.
I am out of ideas to resolve this. what could be the reason?

Comment: Case sensitivity issue?

Comment: I don't believe so. as I said, IDE is automatically coming up with the same path, and I just triple checked paths.

Comment: Try to use `#include ".\libs\Message.h"`

Comment: I have tried that. does not work. but this gives me an Idea. how can I tell Atmel Studio, to change its current working directory? Maybe the working directory is not set as it should.

Comment: Includes should not be relative to current working directory, they should be relative to the location of the C file they are located in.

My guess is that you moved both the C and H files ?

Comment: the current working directory of the project and the C file that the execution starts with, are the same place.